# Special contract for return of sponsorship money in case of early departure

Tags: legal

I work for an international corporation having separate companies in Europe and in USA. I am personally based in Europe.

Being in contact with several US based employees, I was informed that the USA company sponsors some foreign scientists for work in the US company.

As a requirement of them being sponsored is to sign a contract that would require the sponsored employees to return the amount of money the company spent for their sponsorship (probably paying the immigration attorneys) if they do not stay with the company for a year (they resign)?

Is that legal in compliance with immigration laws?

Comment: Yes, that is a legal contract.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere the question is if that practice is in compliance with immigration rules in which employers are required to pay sponsorships? In Greece at least salaries or whatever is set by law for employees are not returnable and those contracts would be in violation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual legality is better discussed in https://law.stackexchange.com/questions

This being said, it's pretty standard practice for many companies to connect large investments into an employee to their continued employment. This can include relocation, sign on bonus, retention bonus, training/college, and, yes, immigration expenses.

I would recommend to carefully read the contract: sometimes the reimbursement is pro-rated, i.e. you pay back half if you stayed half of the agreed time period and there should be a cap of sorts so that you can estimate the worst case.

Comment: Yes, it's pretty common, the legal people sort out the actual details

Comment: I’d add that it’s such a requirement should be written so if they fire you or eliminate your position, you don’t have to pay them back. It would be a pretty shabby practice to do so, but make sure they can’t fire you on the last day and get part of their money back.

Comment: As far as I know to sponsor is an employer requirement by USA law. Can the USA government recognize that as a requirement under certain conditions that the company sets?

Comment: US employers are specifically prohibited from trying to directly recover any of the fees they pay to USCIS & DoL and attorneys from the foreign employee, But the 'loophole' is that the employer can put a 'liquidated damages' type of clause into an employment contract which covers what you've written where the employee leaves before some specified period of time.